# Populate existing Django rows, But there are no rows

Tags: django, database, django-models, migration

I'm trying to migrate my model:

```
class EntitiesModel(models.Model):
    entity_id = models.TextField()
    entity_name = models.TextField()
    entity_type = models.TextField(choices=ENTITY_TYPES)

    #generic key to sources or targets
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

And I get the error:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'entity_name' to entitiesmodel without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

But when I check the database:

```
>>>from forward import models
>>>models.EntitiesModel.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

Do you have any clue what could cause this problem?

Comment: All the options available are described in my answer, so it's up to you to go with the one fits your model structure

Answer (score -1):

These fields can't remain empty, you should add `blank=True` so the database will accept that they can have an empty value.

```
entity_id = models.TextField(blank=True)
entity_name = models.TextField(blank=True)
entity_type = models.TextField(blank=True,choices=ENTITY_TYPES)
```

In case, you don't want them to be empty.
Basically, all your fields are required that means when creating a new instance, you need to fill them all.

```
EntitiesModel.objects.create(
   entity_id = "Value",
   entity_name = "name",
   entity_type = 'type',
   content_object = 'instance',
)
```

Based on your traceback:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'entity_name' to entitie

You're trying to add value that may be *null* `None` in python, Django will raise an error. so you have the argument `null=True` that allows a field to accept a nullable value.

```
entity_id = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
entity_name = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
entity_type = models.TextField(blank=True,choices=ENTITY_TYPES,null=True)
```

If you don't want to store **nullable value**, make sure that the value is not `null` or not `None` before creating the instance

Comment: But what if I don't want to allow them to be empty?

Comment: I'm not creating values, I'm only trying to do migration. You are correct, all values should be required. Based on the traceback " (the database needs something to populate existing rows)." it seems the issue is that the entities that are allready created, but "<QuerySet []>" shows the db is empty.

Comment: before you do migrations, `EntitiesModel` had values?

Comment: No EntitiesModel was Empty